# Amazon SES display sender name using PHP?

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services

I've been following this guide to send emails using Amazon SES: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/786596/How-to-Use-Amazon-SES-to-Send-Email-from-PHP

This worked fine and I was able to send emails.
What I want is to also be able to display the name of the sender instead of just the email address when the receiver gets the email.

What I currently have now is:

```
$msg = array();
$msg['Source'] = "test@myaddress.com";
```

How can I also add a name to this? I was previously using swiftmailer and this worked with "**test@myaddress.com' => 'My Name'**". This, however, doesn't work with amazon SES, at least not in my script.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I figured it out. If anyone has the same issue just format it like in the example below:

```
$msg['Source'] = "My Name <test@myaddress.com>";
```

Comment: Works in Javascript sdk too. params is different though but format of sender name & email is same