# AWS SES SendEmail specifying a name gives 403 Forbidden response

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, aws-php-sdk

I am trying to set up a mail system with Amazon SES service. All is good and working if I use only the email address in `"Source"` parameter. If I try to add a name, I get a `403 Forbidden` HTTP error.

In my PHP code I use AWS SDK:

```
$client = Aws\Ses\SesClient::factory(array(
    'key'    => 'MYAWSKEYXXXXXXXXXX',
    'secret' => 'MYAWSSECRETXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'version'=> 'latest',
    'region' => 'us-east-1'
));

$request = array();
$request['Source'] = "sender@example.com";
$request['Destination']['ToAddresses'] = array("receiver@example.com");
$request['Message']['Subject']['Data'] = 'Mail Subject';
$request['Message']['Body']['Html']['Data'] = 'mail body in HTML: <b>Hello!</b>';

try {
     $result = $client->sendEmail($request);
     $messageId = $result->get('MessageId');
     $message = "Email sent! Message ID: $messageId";

} catch (Exception $e) {
     $message = "The email was not sent. Error message: ";
     $message .= $e->getMessage();
}
```

This code works great, because I have correctly set up my email source in the AWS console with the correct policy. So `"sender@example.com"` in this example can correctly send the email.

Then, if I try to add a name to the `"Source"` param, I don't have any success. I tried:

```
$request['Source'] = "My Name <sender@example.com>";
```

OR

```
$request['Source'] = "'My Name' <sender@example.com>";
```

OR

```
$request['Source'] = "'My Name'<sender@example.com>";
```

OR

```
$request['Source'] = "'My Name <sender@example.com>'";
```

OR

```
$request['Source'] = '"My Name" <sender@example.com>';
```

OR

```
$request['Source'] = '"My Name"<sender@example.com>';
```

OR

```
$request['Source'] = '"My Name <sender@example.com>"';
```

None of the above work.

Does anybody have any idea on how to use SES `sendEmail` with email names?
Some answers I saw here, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33043261), simply don't work. I need to use `sendEmail` and PHP SDK.

Comment: Can the name you are using be spelled with only ASCII characters (ruling out a possible unicode-related issue)?

Comment: Yes @Michael-sqlbot it is only ASCII. The example is similar to my real case. Only english/latin letters and one space between them.

Comment: Hi @alexandresaiz I can't use an external library, but only "sendEmail" function on AWS SES, as specified. Any tips on how to format the request?

Comment: I ran into the same issue. Use the `SourceArn` parameter on `sendEmail()`. None of the variations above worked for me either.

Comment: It looks like this issue isn't solved from AWS. And that's a pity: AWS simply doesn't accept as "Source" anything but a simple email. No names can be passed there.